# Want to show first 100 characters of recent posts in sidebar then "Read More"

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I'm creating my first custom theme on wordpress and trying to get familiar with the codex. I have a "news" section on the bottom right of my sidebar. I want it to show previews of the last two posts or so. Basically want it to just show the title, date, and then the first 100 characters or so of the most recent post followed by a "Read More" anchor. Any idea what function I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li>'.$recent["post_title"].' - '.$recent["post_excerpt"].'<a href="'.get_permalink($recent["ID"]).'">Read More</a></li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts